# How to get cookie value in a template?

Tags: playframework-1.x

What is the way to retrieve the cookies and their values in a template in Play 1.x?

I tried the following :

```
request.cookies.get('comment.name')
```

But it's giving me `play.mvc.Http$Cookie@53ea9981` instead of `Fabien`

I checked in my browser and the cookies exist.

Comment: It's the version of play 1.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see that `request.cookies.get('comment.name')` return an [`Http.Cookie`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.5/index.html).

According to the API, there is a `value` field, which is certainly what you want.

```
request.cookies.get('comment.name').value
```

Comment: Thank you this is working. I just thought it would exist a shorcut to access cookies (like for "session", "flash", "lang", "messages", ...)

Answer (score 2):

`request.cookies` is a `Map` containing `Http.Cookie` values.

You can get the value via

```
request.cookies.get('comment.name').value
```